# set up default routes to common dir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Assume you have a couple of ruby/rails apps running on a server

APP ExmplA:
dir: /foo/bar/ExmplA
runs on http://example.com:4111/

APP ExmplB:
dir: /foo/bar/ExmplB
runs on http://example.com:4112/

APP ExmplC:
dir: /foo/bar/ExmplC
runs on http://example.com:4113/

now i have a common dir
/pool/common/http/
where i want the default root-routes ("/") of the 3 apps to point to.

…so "http://example.com:4113/somedir/something.txt" should map to "/pool/common/http/somedir/something.txt", if not specified otherwise.

What should I enter in the routes.rb of the 3 Apps?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a symbolic link from APP_ROOT/public to your common dir.

This will make anything accessible through root ('/')